# Multiple triggers in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNed.png)

I have a certain object in my game and I'm trying to see whether the object triggers multiple triggers. I tried with the code bellow but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "speed")
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (col.tag == "speed" && col.tag == "point")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How can I recognize if the object only hit "Col1" or "Col1" and "Col2"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnTriggerEnter` is only called when your object is colliding with **one specific trigger**. Thus, the tag of the collider (`col`) can't be `speed` and `point` at the same time.

You have to track if the object is colliding with your triggers using a boolean variable for example :

```
private bool collidingWithSpeed;
private bool collidingWithPoint;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("speed"))
    {
        collidingWithSpeed = true ;
        //do something
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("point"))
    {
        collidingWithPoint = true ;
        //do something
    }

    if( collidingWithSpeed && collidingWithPoint )
    {
         // Do something when your object collided with both triggers
    }
}
// Don't forget to set the variables to false when your object exits the triggers!
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("speed"))
    {
        collidingWithSpeed = false;
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("point"))
    {
        collidingWithPoint = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Hellium's answer would work perfectly, I personally prefer using a list to store all my colliding objects (or at least some of them). Like so

```
private readonly List<string> collidingTags = new List<string>();

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    //Add some kind of filter or safety check if needed
    collidingTags.Add(collider.tag);
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    //Add some kind of safety check if needed
    collidingTags.Remove(collider.tag);
}
```

In theory, this is far less efficient in terms of performances (compared to storing a bool) but stills, it adds a nice layer of flexibility.
In practice, the difference in performances is incredibly small so you decide!

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)